# Conditional indent of paragraph

Tags: indentation

Is there a way to indent paragraphs if they follow "long lines" of text?

Graphical example of what I want my text to look like

[image: Paragraph example]

Here, only the paragraph "Duis autem..." is indented, because it follows a "long line". I need this indentation, because otherwise the new paragraph would not be visible.

This example was done manually by using `\noindent` on most of the paragraphs. Is there a package that can do this for me, automatically?

Comment: You either indent all paragraphs (with the possible exception of the one immediately following a title) or none. The former method has been the preferred one for some centuries.

Comment: Indentation or separation helps the reader to find the start of a new paragraph. All he needs is to scan the left side of the text block to find the paragraphs. But if the indentation is missing sometimes, he has now to scan both sides of the text while keeping the scans horizontal synchronized to compare the right side with the left to find the paragraphs. This requires much more brain activity and the readability is therefore decreased.

Comment: Imho it would be much better is you would set `\parfillskip` to some positive value to avoid full last lines. Your layout looks rather odd.

Comment: It is possible (just about) (you can use `\predisplaysize` to measure the last line) but as Ulrike says it is much better to ensure that `\parfillskip` has a minimum size, so long lines do not occur if they bother you.